# confluent 5.0.1 upgrade to 7.0.1

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Trying to upgrade confluent I have checked upgrade link:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/7.0.1/installation/upgrade.html
I found inside it said in the Preparation section:

```
- If you’re running a Confluent Platform version that’s lower than 5.3.1, upgrade to 5.3.1 before upgrading to 6.1.x or higher.
```

And this point has been in the Preparation points since version 6.1.0 upgrade guide: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/6.1.0/installation/upgrade.html
it's missing version 6.0.5 upgrade guide:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/6.0.5/installation/upgrade.html

Now, what I need to know is the reason behind this point, why can't I upgrade directly and what would I lose if I did?

Another question: Since this point is missing in version 6.0.5 (Latest before 6.1.x), can I upgrade to 6.0.5 directly from 5.0.1?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might corrupt your Kafka broker if you go directly to the highest version

Note in Kafka 2.1, it is impossible to downgrade based on the log format change - https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade

> Once you have changed the inter.broker.protocol.version to the latest version, it will not be possible to downgrade to a version prior to 2.1.